# What is the difference between scope and model within a directive definition in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

I was wondering about the difference between `scope` and `model` within a directive.

The following 2 directives behave exactly the same:

```
angular.module( 'exampleApp', [] )
.directive( 'exampleDirective1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { // using scope here
      info: '='
    },
    template: '<div><span>{{ info }}<span> <input ng-model="info"></div>'
  };
} )
.directive( 'exampleDirective2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    model: { // using model here
      info: '='
    },
    template: '<div><span>{{ info }}<span> <input ng-model="info"></div>'
  };
} );
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: scope defines an isolate scope, and allows defining info by passing an expression as the info attribute of the directive. model is just a random field of your directive object, that angular doesn't care about. Those two directives don't behave the same way at all. Use `<example-directiveX info="42"></example-directiveX>`, and you'll see. http://plnkr.co/edit/SuCzIFYwQ85lAIUufPz6?p=preview

Comment: Nice! I only tested my code with a given variable from a parent directive. Thanks for your answer!